# How to add custom external video filter to ffmpeg at runtime?

Tags: video, filter, ffmpeg

Trying to build [ffplay](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/fftools/ffplay.c) app that uses ffmpeg [LGPL build](https://www.ffmpeg.org/legal.html) with custom filter that I want to plug in during runtime. Differently from [adding custom filter during compilation](https://fossies.org/linux/ffmpeg/doc/writing_filters.txt) described scenario is not documented, thus tried to experiment. Tried executing [avfilter_register](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.2/group__lavfi.html#ga3db814dea5d918f88af888d484f77fb8) and [avfilter_graph_alloc_filter](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.2/group__lavfi.html#gaa9af17ecf4c5c87307b57cf08411088b) functions before [avfilter_graph_parse_ptr](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.2/group__lavfi.html#ga34f4ff420bd58da6747a3ff1fbedd001) with avfilter_graph_parse_ptr resulting in -22 return value (Invalid argument).

Filter graph string: `[in] split [T1], fifo, [T2] overlay=0:H/2 [out]; [T1] fifo, crop=iw:ih/2:0:ih/2, my_edgedetect=low=0.1:high=0.4 [T2]`

Lines added to [configure_filtergraph](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/fftools/ffplay.c#L1797-L1838) function in ffplay.c:

```
        if ((ret = avfilter_register(&ff_vf_edgedetect)) < 0)
            goto fail;
        if ((ret = avfilter_graph_alloc_filter(graph, &ff_vf_edgedetect, ff_vf_edgedetect.name)) < 0)
            goto fail;
```

[Custom edge detect filter](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/e831f60100a06ea01865aa0d9d7566b930a7ce62/libavfilter/vf_edgedetect.c) name (AVFilter.name) changed to my_edgedetect.

---

What is the proper way to register custom filter during runtime?

---

P.S.
Same question on [Zeranoa forum](https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=7687&p=16623)

Comment: I believe the assumption is, if you have to modify the code to call the register function, you can just include the filter. what is the purpose  of this? Is it an attempt to appease the license while including a proprietary plugin?. In that case you would probably need to make the ffmpeg modifications more generic and able to load arbitrary shared objects.

Comment: Yes that's exactly the attempt - plugging in proprietary filter. Could you please elaborate on "In that case you would probably need to make the ffmpeg modifications more generic and able to load arbitrary shared objects. "